# login to web site using python3 and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i need a little help on my little project on learning python web scraping.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar

base_url = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=flickrsignin&.pc=8190&.scrumb=0&.pd=c%3DH6T9XcS72e4mRnW3NpTAiU8ZkA--&.intl=in&.lang=en&mg=1&.done=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.yahoo.com%2Fconfig%2Fvalidate%3F.src%3Dflickrsignin%26.pc%3D8190%26.scrumb%3D0%26.pd%3Dc%253DJvVF95K62e6PzdPu7MBv2V8-%26.intl%3Din%26.done%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.flickr.com%252Fsignin%252Fyahoo%252F%253Fredir%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.flickr.com%25252F"
login_action = "/config/login?.src=flickrsignin&.pc=8190&.scrumb=0&.pd=c%3DH6T9XcS72e4mRnW3NpTAiU8ZkA--&.intl=in&.lang=en&mg=1&.done=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.yahoo.com%2Fconfig%2Fvalidate%3F.src%3Dflickrsignin%26.pc%3D8190%26.scrumb%3D0%26.pd%3Dc%253DJvVF95K62e6PzdPu7MBv2V8-%26.intl%3Din%26.done%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.flickr.com%252Fsignin%252Fyahoo%252F%253Fredir%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.flickr.com%25252F"

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener =  urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent',
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) '
     'AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/13.0.782.13 Safari/535.1'))
]


login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    'login-username' : 'username',
    'login-passwd' : 'password',
    'remember_me' : True
})
login_data = login_data.encode('ascii')
login_url = base_url + login_action
response = opener.open(login_url, login_data)
print (response.read())
```

i have tried loggin in, but the output is returned as in the login page html, could anyone help me out to login to this site?

Answer (score 2):

Try read read more on request with beautifulsoup. the `User[email]` is only the `username input name` and `User[password]` is that of the password. Though the code below can only login inside a site without `crsf_token` protection

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3 import add_stderr_logger
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re, random, datetime
random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())

add_stderr_logger()

session = requests.Session()
per_session = session.post(url, 
data={'User[email]':'your_email', 'User[password]':'your_password'})
#you can now associate request with beautifulsoup
try:
   #it assumed that by now you are logged so we can now use .get and fetch any page of your choice
   bsObj = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).content, 'lxml')
except HTTPError as e:
   print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not storing the `session token` received on login.instead of doing that manually you can use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html) for handling the sign in session.

[here](http://stockrt.github.io/p/handling-html-forms-with-python-mechanize-and-BeautifulSoup/) is a nice article for how to do that.

Comment: mechanize is not compatible with python 3, check mechanicalsoup or robobrowser instead